# Relative and absolute positioning. Force a logo move to the corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, responsive-images

Suppose I have such a situation:

[image]

You can see a few main parts:

- The panel (border red)
- The image
- The logo
- The title

And I need this setup:

[image]

So the logo needs to get up. Usually, every time I try to make the image `absolute` and the logo `relative`, then float it to right it works, but I loose the title which also goes under the image.

And I can't make the title relative and push it from top with some value, because the image is responsive and changes it's `height`.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .body {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .panel {
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color: blue;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .logo {
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            width: 100px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVxPtnNvc1ZwknRSdJZIPjrmUHitXdUU_-TT3wuIF-mWND6sXV" class="img-responsive" alt="picture nature">
        <div class="logo">
            I'm a logo
        </div>
        <h1>I'm a title, hello</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check this url.
http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/YWpmMb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've added `position:relative` to the container and `position:absolute; top:0; right:0` to the logo

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
}
.panel {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 50px;
    position:relative;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
.logo {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gusz58x/

Since the image is not moving and needs to change it's dimensions, you can just make the logo move to wherever you need it to with `absolute`.  If you make it absolute, you need to give its container (or at least the container you would like it to be 'contained' in) `position:relative;` so it has somewhere to be.

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii, You got it!

Answer (score 3):

Relative on panel. Absolute on logo top: 0, right: 0
ntgCleaner was 34sec faster so accept his answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .body {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .panel {
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color: blue;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .logo {
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            width: 100px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVxPtnNvc1ZwknRSdJZIPjrmUHitXdUU_-TT3wuIF-mWND6sXV" class="img-responsive" alt="picture nature">
        <div class="logo">
            I'm a logo
        </div>
        <h1>I'm a title, hello</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hahaha, Accept whichever answer you like!

Comment: So, you made the image's position to be relative to the nearest relative parent?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii You don't need to do anything to the image.  If you want to move the logo, change that position type

Comment: Logo's position*. Mistaken.

Comment: Relative is a position relative to itself. So if you were to say do top: -30px, the element would move up because a relative element's original position is top: 0, left: 0; Absolute is relative to it's parent, if that parent is not static (ie it is fixed, absolute, relative).

Comment: btw this is is not a matter of if answers first, has to be the accepted answer forcefully, the OP has to choose the answer which was more helpful to OP. because of that type of mentality SO is full of crappy answers

Comment: In this case all answers are identical, my *mentality* isn't like a quiz show contestant, just being considerate.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the `position:relative` in the parent `.panel` and use `position:absolute` in `.logo` with `top`\ `right` set to  `0`

If you don't have `position:relative` in parent, and using `position:absolute` that element will go out the flow regarding the DOM

> **absolute**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if
>   any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block. Absolutely
>   positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any
>   other margins.

See more info about [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
}
.panel {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 50px
}
img {
  width: 100%
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTVxPtnNvc1ZwknRSdJZIPjrmUHitXdUU_-TT3wuIF-mWND6sXV" class="img-responsive" alt="picture nature">
  <div class="logo">
    I'm a logo
  </div>
  <h1>I'm a title, hello</h1>
</div>
```